# Change small elements (SVG) in main SVG image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

i want to ask you about change SVG elements into SVG main element.

Let's suppose that the black square is a main SVG element. I want to change element 1,2 and 3 to diffrent SVG element. I need to do this by JS code but i don't know how to prepare SVG image for this action. When i simply change the path of element in SVG tag, the changed element isn't in good location on main SVG image.

What i will need to know about SVG and changing SVG elements path to achieve wanted result? Because, copying the path from new SVG image, just to main SVG image as element doesn't work well

Maybe easiest way to understand it, is the shoe customize. On main SVG i have a shoe image with raw elements of shoe (TONGUE and HEEL). I have 5 diffrent TONGUES and HEELS. When i click on shoe TONGUE, i want to be able to choose one of five TONGUES (same with HEEL). When i choose new TONGUE for shoe, the main SVG image need to change TONGUE to new choosen TONGUE (same with HEEL).

I think that i need to change element path to change the image but i don't know if it's a proper way

Thank You in Advance,

Best Regards.

[image]

Comment: i would suggest using canvas, because canvases x,y coordinates is much easier to work with, rather than svg path

Answer (score 3):

I would use `<symbol>`s with the same `viewBox` or al least the same ratio. You can `<use>` those symbols and the `x`,`y`, `width` and `height` would be always the same for the same spot.

Next comes an example where I'm changing the icon dynamically on click.

```js
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";


demo.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  let actual = volume.getAttribute('xlink:href');
  if(actual == "#volume_up"){
    volume.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#volume_off');
  }else{volume.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#volume_up');}
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg id="demo" viewBox = "0 0 100 100"> 
<symbol id="volume_up" viewBox='0 0 24 24'>
  <title>volume up</title>
  <path d='M3 9v6h4l5 5V4L7 9H3zm13.5 3c0-1.77-1.02-3.29-2.5-4.03v8.05c1.48-.73 2.5-2.25 2.5-4.02zM14 3.23v2.06c2.89.86 5 3.54 5 6.71s-2.11 5.85-5 6.71v2.06c4.01-.91 7-4.49 7-8.77s-2.99-7.86-7-8.77z'></path>

</symbol>
<symbol id="volume_off" viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>volume off</title>
    <path d='M16.5 12c0-1.77-1.02-3.29-2.5-4.03v2.21l2.45 2.45c.03-.2.05-.41.05-.63zm2.5 0c0 .94-.2 1.82-.54 2.64l1.51 1.51C20.63 14.91 21 13.5 21 12c0-4.28-2.99-7.86-7-8.77v2.06c2.89.86 5 3.54 5 6.71zM4.27 3L3 4.27 7.73 9H3v6h4l5 5v-6.73l4.25 4.25c-.67.52-1.42.93-2.25 1.18v2.06c1.38-.31 2.63-.95 3.69-1.81L19.73 21 21 19.73l-9-9L4.27 3zM12 4L9.91 6.09 12 8.18V4z'></path>
</symbol>
  
  <use id="volume" xlink:href="#volume_off" x="35"  y="35" width="30" height="30"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Simple and reliable solution. Good answer. (+)